# Excel find End of Range then Select Range and Copy

Tags: excel, copy, range, vba

this may or may not have been asked yet.

I am trying to copy a Range of Cells from one worksheet to another using a macro. the problem I am having is that the Range I want to copy varies drastically every time the macro is run.

For example I wan to Copy Range("A2:P64") on first run, then when i run the data again the start of the Range is still A2, but the end of the range may be P25 or p90000.  It is always Column P and (x variable) Row.

I have tried things like this:

```
Dim past As Worksheet
Dim countHist As String
Dim view As Worksheet
Dim countView As String

Set view = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BlueSteel Errors")
Set past = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Historical")

countView = view.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
countHist = past.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox ("P" & countView) ' This currently gives the count of 53, so output is P53

view.Range("A2:P & countView").Select   ' THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE.. should look
'should resemble view.Range("A2:P53").Select
'EVERYTHING ELSE APPEARS TO WORK

Selection.Copy
past.Select
Range("A" & countHist).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I cannot find a way to determine the last line that text exists, and then append that number to the end of the Range field so i can Select and append to the other sheet.. I only need the data from A2 - Px  not All of the excess fields beyond P.   Perhaps I need to copy then delete that.

Comment: It should be like this `view.Range("A2:P" & countView).Select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please... Please...Please... Please...Please... Please...Please... Please...Please... Please...Please... Please...Please... Please...Please... Please...Please... Please... do not use `.Select` [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Also there are couple of errors in your code

1. You have declared `countHist` and `countView` as `String`. It should be `Long`
2. Anything within quotes is a string. So `"A2:P & countView"` is a string. You need `"A2:P" & countView`
3. You need to add `1` to the last row of destination sheet so that you do not overwrite the last row.

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim past As Worksheet, view As Worksheet
    Dim countHist As Long, countView As Long

    Set view = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BlueSteel Errors")
    Set past = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Historical")

    countView = view.Cells(view.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    countHist = past.Cells(past.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    '~~> Do a direct copy paste instead of selecting first
    view.Range("A2:P" & countView).Copy past.Range("A" & countHist)
End Sub
```

You may need to use `.Find` to find the last row is not all cells are filled up in a particular row. More about finding last row [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Comment: Thank you.. that is very close to what my original code looked like, and yes the Select feature has its downside..  Thank you for spotting my "Oversight... :D  "   

This is reason I dont code for more than an hour or two at a time.. The code starts to look the same and always right.  Even when its wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `End(xlUp)` function.

So update your problematic line

from

```
view.Range("A2:P & countView").Select   ' THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE..
```

to

```
view.Range("A2:" & view.Range("P" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address).Select
```